# While transfering App its showing "Your App contain Passbook integration"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

while transfering app i got this error message like "Your App contain Passbook integration. So you can not transfer App"  but actually my app does not contain passbook integration so how can i solve this?

Comment: did you checked references for passlibrary? any of your library uses passlibrary? You cannot transfer app if it contains passbook entitlements https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html. If you feel those were added by accidenty, release an update in existing app removing those entitlements and once approved you can transfer it to new account